# Ubuntu can't boot with ACPI on - Samsung NP700Z4AH Notebook - Radeon HD 6750M

Tags: boot, drivers, radeon, acpi, gpu-driver

I've installed Ubuntu 16.04 in a Samsung Notebook but can't boot without disabling acpi. I appended `acpi=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` and updated grub options with `update-grub`. Now every time I try to turn the machine off , it stops and I have to turn it off directly in the on/off button. Is this a driver problem? How can I debbug and find which hardware are failing? I suspect it is related with my video card.

**Output of `lspci` for video cards:**

```
$ lspci | grep VGA | awk '{print $1}'
00:02.0
01:00.0

$ sudo lspci -v -s 00:02.0
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

$ sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Radeon HD 6750M
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0720000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel modules: radeon
```

**Output of `lspci -v`:**

```
$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00003000-00003fff
    Memory behind bridge: c0700000-c07fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000afffffff
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 24
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at 4000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25
    Memory at c0805000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at c080a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 27
    Memory at c0800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c0600000-c06fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0400000-00000000c04fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 19
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: c0500000-c05fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 2
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at c0809000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd HM65 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    I/O ports at 4088 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4094 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4080 [size=8]
    I/O ports at 4090 [size=4]
    I/O ports at 4060 [size=32]
    Memory at c0808000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Capabilities: [b0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
    Flags: medium devsel
    Memory at c0804000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at efa0 [size=32]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Whistler [Radeon HD 6630M/6650M/6750M/7670M/7690M] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd Radeon HD 6750M
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at c0700000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    I/O ports at 3000 [size=256]
    Expansion ROM at c0720000 [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [a0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel modules: radeon

02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak] (rev 34)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6230 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 26
    Memory at c0600000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 22
    I/O ports at 2000 [size=256]
    Memory at c0404000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Memory at c0400000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
    Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
    Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169

04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at c0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [68] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [78] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] Express Legacy Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

How can I fix this and enable acpi again?